# How can I write a vb event that outputs the current record of a form to XML

Tags: xml, ms-access-2010

This code below works... BUT, its stops and asks user for options and I need this to be automatic in the background triggered by an event.

```
DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputForm, "frmSNcert-CB", acFormatXML, "C:\Master\" & Me.ClientCode & "-" & Format(DATE, "yyyymmdd") & "-" & Me.detailSN & ".xml"
```

Comment: What type of options?

Comment: i need for it to automatically pick the output to be XML - then, I need for it to go into the options (on the popup box when doing manually) and select current record.